# Browser needs to be reopened to accept new JavaScript changes, isn't cache

Tags: caching

Sometimes I have what seems to be a cache problem and I am using incognito mode and inprivate window to prevent this.  However, sometimes neither of these works, and I must close and open the browser. I don't think this works every time either.  This caused me a big problem because I was needing to see if my code changes did change the outcome.  How can I make sure that my changes are always registered?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome and the DevTools is open, you can click and hold the Refresh icon in front of the address bar, and a box will pop up, and you can choose to "Hard Reload" or even "Empty Cache and Hard Reload": [image]

Comment: Thank you, hopefully this will work every time, is this true?

Comment: This is will solve momentary the issue, you have to investigate further to found the root cause

Answer (score 0):

[image: Look Related Question]

Look Related Question
Look Related Question
Look Related Question
Look Related Question
Look Related Question
Look Related Question
Look Related Question